# How to specify data store class name while configuring Amazon S3 in AEM 6.0

Tags: amazon-s3, aem

We are configuring amazon S3 with AEM 6.0.

For previous version of AEM there is a way to configure the data store class. ->https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/s3-connector.html

```
<..put xml here..>
```

but in 6.0 documentation there's no mention of where the S3DataStore class is specified

Just wondering how the S3 DataStore class to be used is handled in 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the AEM 6.0 documentation as the link in your question is for 5.6

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/data-store-config.html#Data Store Configurations

See the section titled "Upgrading to version 1.2 of the Amazon S3 Connector" as it has detailed steps for extracting and configuring the S3 connecters.

All the configurations go under crx-quickstart/install folder rather than the old way of XML files. It's much simpler in 6.x now.